# Assert List of Maps in Java ignoring the order

Tags: java, assertion

Is there any way where I can assert 2 lists of Maps ignoring the order? thanks

Example:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> dataList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> headers1 = new ArrayList<>();
        headers1.add("Header1");
        headers1.add("Header2");
        headers1.add("Header3");

        Map<String, Object> dataMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        dataMap1.put(headers1.get(0), "testData1");
        dataMap1.put(headers1.get(1), "testData2");
        dataMap1.put(headers1.get(2), "testData3");

        Map<String, Object> dataMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        dataMap2.put(headers1.get(0), "testData4");
        dataMap2.put(headers1.get(1), "testData5");
        dataMap2.put(headers1.get(2), "testData6");

        dataList1.add(dataMap1);
        dataList1.add(dataMap2);

List<Map<String, Object>> dataList2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> headers3 = new ArrayList<>();
        headers3.add("Header1");
        headers3.add("Header2");
        headers3.add("Header3");

        Map<String, Object> dataMap3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        dataMap3.put(headers3.get(0), "testData1");
        dataMap3.put(headers3.get(1), "testData2");
        dataMap3.put(headers3.get(2), "testData3");

        Map<String, Object> dataMap4 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        dataMap4.put(headers3.get(0), "testData4");
        dataMap4.put(headers3.get(1), "testData5");
        dataMap4.put(headers3.get(2), "testData6");

        dataList2.add(dataMap4);
        dataList2.add(dataMap3);

        System.out.println(dataList1);
        System.out.println(dataList2);
```

and the results would be:

```
[{Header1=testData1, Header2=testData2, Header3=testData3}, {Header1=testData4, Header2=testData5, Header3=testData6}]
[{Header1=testData4, Header2=testData5, Header3=testData6}, {Header1=testData1, Header2=testData2, Header3=testData3}]
```

I want to get a TRUE result since they are actually the same but with different order. thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Just to add. I am trying to check if the 2 lists of maps are equal from 2 different sources (Excel file vs Database data). so there's a chance that the lists of data have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what a list is for. If you don't care about the order, you should use a `Set` instead.
However if the order is important but you just want to make sure they contain the same Maps then you could just convert them to Sets for the assertion:

```
new HashSet<Map<String, Object>>(dataList1).equals(new HashSet<Map<String, Object>>(dataList2))
```

Comment: Note that sets drop duplicates, so this may tell you that lists of uneven size (or of the same size but different multiplicity of elements) are "equal".

Comment: i think a Set would not help here, since the "equals()" method will not do a deep comparison of the objects in the set. he would need to implement equals() (and perhaps even hashCode) on his own in order to make it work. (remember HashSet is implemented by HashMap)

Comment: @AndyTurner that's true. I'm not entirely sure if this is relevant though. It seems to me that the assertion is meant to check whether or not the lists contain the same objects. If a check for duplicates is required then this will not suffice. Then you'd have to do check the List item by item.

Comment: @TomElias I don't think so. The objects in the Set are of the type LinkedHashMap which implements proper equals and hashCode methods. So this shouldn't be a problem. Also if you don't implement equals an hashCode your class just has the default implementation of those methods which checks for identity rather than equality. That's still valid if that is what you want. The only problem is when you only override one of the two methods. But that's a different discussion altogether ;-)

Comment: @TomElias note that sets _will_ call `equals()` on the elements, in fact it calls `containsAll()` which in turn calls `contains(e)` for each element and that either calls `equals()` on the elements of the other set/collection directly or in case of `HashSet` calls `map.contains(e)` which in turn uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` of the elements.

Comment: @geanakuch it may or may not be relevant; that's why it's worth calling out before OP bets the house on this approach :)

Comment: @AndyTurner Can't disagree with that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the case you're describing the value lists would rather have "bag" semantics, i.e. sets which contain duplicates.

To compare those you need to write your own comparison logic (or find a library that provides it, e.g. [Apache Commons Collections' CollectionUtils#isEqualCollection()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#isEqualCollection-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) or [Hamcrest's Matchers#containsInAnyOrder()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection))) since the default methods won't help. The assert would then be something like `assertTrue(mapsAreEqual(actual, expected))` or `assertEqual(new MapEqualWrapper(actual), new MapEqualWrapper(expected))` where `MapEqualWrapper` would implement the logic in its `equals()`.

For the check you could sort the lists (or copies of them) and do a traditional comparison or use a frequency map (after other checks of course):

- first check the sizes - if they are different the lists aren't equal
- build a frequency map for the first list, i.e. increment the value by 1 for each occurence
- check the elements in the second list by decreasing the occurences and removing any frequencies that hit 0

  - if you hit an element that has no entry in the frequency map you can stop already since the bags aren't equal

Sorting and comparing would be easier to implement with just a couple of lines but time complexity would be O(n*log(n)) due to the sorting.

On the other hand, time complexity for using the frequency map would basically be O(n) (iterations are O(n) and map put/get/remove should be O(1) in theory). This, however, shouldn't matter unless you need to quickly compare large lists and thus I'd go with the sort and compare method first.